# Nearest neighbours

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to find a lightweight way to find nearby objects in three.js.
I have a bunch of cubes, and I want each cube to be able to determine the nearest cubes to it on demand.

Is there a better way to do this than just iterating through all objects and calculating the distance between them? I know the renderer does something similar to what I want when it sorts to find the order to render with, but I'm not getting too far just trying to read the three.js code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The renderer is doing the same thing you're describing but you may want to use KDTrees in your case.

Have a look at this example:
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_nearestneighbour.html

Comment: Depending on your use case, also have a look at http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_octree.html.